# Split String without cutting a key word in resulting Strings

Tags: java, regex

Let's assume I have a String that contains data in square brackets. How to split content of this String using a specific word.
Below I show simplified example of what I would like to do. My string:

```
"[Chapter 1]
[Lorem ipsum 123]
[Lorem ipsum 456]
Lorem ipsum 789
[Chapter 2]
[Lorem ipsum 012]
[Lorem ipsum 345]"
```

My attempt:

```
public void method() { 
   String myString = "[Chapter 1][Lorem ipsum 123][Lorem ipsum 456]Lorem ipsum 789[Chapter 2][Lorem ipsum 012][Lorem ipsum 345]"; 
   String []myArray = myString.split("\[Chapter"); for (String var : myArray) {          
      System.out.println(var); 
   } 
}
```

I want to split my String every time when "[Chapter" is present. Results of splitting:

First String:

```
"[Chapter 1]
[Lorem ipsum 123]
[Lorem ipsum 456]
Lorem ipsum 789"
```

Second String:

```
"[Chapter 2]
[Lorem ipsum 789]
[Lorem ipsum 012]"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some relevant code to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String str="[Chapter 1][Lorem ipsum 123][Lorem ipsum 456]Lorem ipsum 789[Chapter 2][Lorem ipsum 012][Lorem ipsum 345]";
String str1[]=str.split("(?=\\[Chapter )");
for(String s : str1)
System.out.println(s);
```

> Demo Link
>
> https://repl.it/repls/NavyblueBetterJavadoc

Comment: For better accuracy you should use `(?=\\[Chapter \\d+\\])`. +1

Comment: thanks for the suggestion :-)